# I would like to create a non-free Jira plugin. How to create my own validate license form on JIRA UPM?

Tags: jira-plugin

I don't know how to create my own validate license form on JIRA UPM. I would like to create a non-free plugin and want to generate license key for user to activate the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This had not been built into the [Universal Plugin Manager (UPM)](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/UPM/Universal+Plugin+Manager) at the time of your question, but Atlassian has meanwhile (silently) released [UPM version 2.0](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/23915?versionId=1010598), which includes major feature additions concerning this use case specifically.

Please refer to the extensive beginner level tutorial [Adding Licensing Support to your Marketplace-Ready Plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/UPM/Adding+Licensing+Support+to+your+Marketplace-Ready+Plugin) for details, in addition you might want to review [Selling Your Plugin in the Atlassian Marketplace](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/UPM/Adding+Licensing+Support+to+your+Marketplace-Ready+Plugin) for a more generic overview on how to offer a commercial plugin as well.